# Random Walk Upper-Bound. For any symmetric Random Walk, absolute value of partial sum $S_n$ never exceeds $\sqrt{2 \pi n}+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}2}$?

Tags: random-walk, upper-lower-bounds

Is it possible to prove that for any symmetric Random Walk, the absolute value of its partial sum $S_n$ never exceeds $\sqrt{2 \pi n}+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}2}\quad\large?$

[image]

I run some simulation, clearly for initial value it is not true, but for large $n$ it seems true that it is a real absolute bound.

Comment: You might want to check my edit is what you originally wrote

Comment: Never is asking for a lot. What about hardly ever?

Comment: Take the sample walk "all up" of length $n$: $(1,1,...,1,1)$, its final position (equal to its absolute value as it is positive) is $n$, so larger than your value for $n>2$. It also has positive probability $2^{-n}$.

Answer (score 1):

No

For example you might with positive probability get nine $+1$s in a row.

But $\sqrt{18 \pi}+\sqrt{\pi / 2} \lt 9$.

More substantially, the [law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) says $\displaystyle \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2n \log\log n}} = 1$ almost surely. For big enough $n$ you will have $\dfrac{\sqrt{2n \log\log n}}{\sqrt{2n \pi} + \sqrt{\pi/2}} \gt 1$.

Answer (score 0):

My motivation was this.

The average number of zeros for Sn is Sqrt[2/Pi] for every interval
2n+1. So if after k^2 steps the value of Sn is greater than (2k+1)*Sqrt[Pi/2]
than in the next interval 2k+1 the possibility for Sn to become zero would be 
impossible. Something wrong?